# How to update after union query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 table as seen below,

```
coin
----
chanceNo
userID
coin_code
date

coin2
----
chanceNo
userID
coin_code
date
```

My query to find where '12345' is at which table, as seen below (which is correct and successful search & match),

```
SELECT coin_code from coin WHERE coin_code='12345' UNION 
Select coin_code from coin2 WHERE coin_code='12345';
```

However, i am stuck with updating query after search. How can i update after i found coin_code='12345'.

I know that the basic update query is like this,

```
UPDATE coin2 SET userID='name', date='12-12-12' WHERE coin_code='12345'
```

But what if the '12345' is in another table, coin? May i know, how to write this query?

Comment: is your first query finding which table got the value `12345`?

Comment: Deepak, yeah correct, first query is to find which table got the value 12345 and once found, i want to update. But how to update with another query or smth?

Answer (score 2):

This query will tell you which table the coin_code was found in:

```
SELECT "coin" which_table, coin_code
FROM coin
WHERE coin_code = '12345'
UNION
SELECT "coin2" which_table, coin_code
FROM coin2
WHERE coin_code = '12345'
```

Now that you have the table name, you can substitute it into an UPDATE query:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_stmt);
$upd_stmt = mysqli_prepare("UPDATE {$row[which_table]} SET userID = ?, date = ? WHERE coin_code = ?");
```

Comment: looks like he is struck with the second part!!

Comment: Hi Barmar, i dont understand what you mean by this line, [SELECT "coin" which_table, coin_code], what is 'which_table'?? how come both coin and coin2 have same name, "which_table"? 

Or, are you saying that make both table, coin and coin2 into temporary one table, which_table?

Comment: `which_table` is the header name.. like how you use `coin_code as code`

Comment: `which_table` is an alias for the first column of the result. It will contain either "coin" or "coin2" depending on which query in the union found the matching row.

Comment: Hmm, i dont get it, why, select 'coin' which_table? coin is a table name.. Not any column header name. Sorry to bother you

Answer (score 1):

Extending Barmar's answer you can do something like this,

```
$sql="SELECT 'coin' which_table, coin_code
      FROM coin
      WHERE coin_code = '12345'
      UNION
      SELECT 'coin2' which_table, coin_code
      FROM coin2
      WHERE coin_code = '12345'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

     //Now updating the table
     $sql_update = "UPDATE {$row['which_table']} SET userID='name', date='12-12-12' 
               WHERE coin_code='{$row['coin_code']}'";
     mysqli_query($sql_update);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i dont get it, why, select 'coin' which_table? coin is a table name.. Not any column header name. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Amazinglykai It's just a literal string being returned -- notice that each branch of the UNION returns a different string. This allows you to know which branch found the matching line, so you'll know which table to update in the second query.

Comment: hmm, i tried your code, i wasnt able to find the matching coin_code and thus, cannot update as well..